# If modulus of each one of eigenvalues of $B$ is less than $1$, then $B^k\rightarrow 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $B$ be a $n\times n$ matrix and let $X$ be the set of all eigenvalues of $B$. Prove that if $|m|<1$ then $\lim \limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}B^k=0$, where $m=\max X$.

Thanks.

Actually, there isn't a order involved. Sorry. The correct question is:

Let $B$ be a $n\times n$ matrix, $X$ be the set of all eigenvalues of $B$ and $|X|=\{|x|;x\in X\}$. Prove that if $|m|<1$ then $\lim \limits_{k\rightarrow\infty}B^k=0$, where $m=\max |X|$.

Comment: Using $\max (X)$ assumes there is an order involved. What about if there are complex eigenvalues?

Comment: More generally, in a unital Banach algebra, we have the spectral radius formula $\rho(b)=\lim_{k\rightarrow +\infty}\|b^k\|^\frac{1}{k}$. So $\rho(b)<1$ implies easily $\lim \|b^k\|=0$. Regardless of the norm (as long as it is Banach algebra norm and satifies in particular $\|ab\|\leq \|a\|\|b\|$).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my answer I'll be assuming that the OP means that $X$ is the set of absolute values of the eigenvalues of $B$, (as suggested by the title), which makes $m$ be $B$'s [spectral radius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius).

Consider the [Jordan Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326688/why-the-nth-power-of-a-jordan-matrix-involves-the-binomial-coefficient) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Powers).

Let $J$ be a jordan matrix for $B$. Then $B=P^{-1}JP$ and $(B^k)_{k\in \Bbb N}$ converges if, and only if, $(J^k)_{k\in \Bbb N}$ converges.

Now consider the powers of $J$. The above links should make it clear that if $\color{grey}{m=\rho (J)=}\rho (B)<1$, then $\lim \limits_{k\to +\infty }(J^k)=0$ and the result follows.

Comment: Is the definition of $J$ that implies $\rho (J)=\rho (B)$?

Comment: Yes, because $J$ and $B$ share the same eigenvalues.