# If the absolute values of all the eigenvalues of $C$ are smaller than $1$, then $I-C$ is non-singular.

Tags: matrix-calculus

I am reading "Matrix Calculus"(in Japanese) by Masahiko Saito.

There is the following proposition in this book:

> Let $I$ be an identity matrix.
> Let $C$ be a square matrix.
> Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} I&B \\ O&C \end{pmatrix}$.
> If the absolute values of all the eigenvalues of $C$ are smaller than $1$, then $I-C$ is non-singular and $$\lim_{p\to\infty} A^p = \begin{pmatrix}I&B(I-C)^{-1}\\O&O\end{pmatrix}.$$

> Proof:
> By assumption, $I-C$ is non-singular.
> By the previous proposition, $$A^p=\begin{pmatrix} I&B(I-C)^{-1}(I-C^p) \\ O&C^p\end{pmatrix}.$$
> By theorem 3.3.8, $$\lim_{p\to\infty} C^p = O.$$
> Therefore, $$\lim_{p\to\infty} A^p = \begin{pmatrix}I&B(I-C)^{-1}\\O&O\end{pmatrix}.$$

We must show $I-C$ is non-singular, but by mistake, the author wrote it is non-singular by assumption.

I wanna know a proof of the following proposition:

> If the absolute values of all the eigenvalues of $C$ are smaller than $1$, then $I-C$ is non-singular.

My attempt:
$(I-C)(I+C+\dots+C^{p-1}) = I - C^p$.
I know $\lim_{p\to\infty} C^p = O$.
So, $\lim_{p\to\infty} (I - C^p) = I$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $I-C$ is singular it has a zero eigenvalue. But the eigenvalues of $I-C$ are $1-\lambda$ as $\lambda$ runs through the eigenvalues of $C$. So $C$ has an eigenvalue $1$ - a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elegant answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, I will use that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \mathbf{C}^n = \mathbf{O}$, proven in [If modulus of each one of eigenvalues of $B$ is less than $1$, then $B^k\rightarrow 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409601/if-modulus-of-each-one-of-eigenvalues-of-b-is-less-than-1-then-bk-rightar)

Now, we consider the homogeneous system
\begin{equation*}
(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{C})\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0},   
\end{equation*}
where $\mathbf{0}$ is a column of $0$'s with the same length as the order of $\mathbf{C}$. Then, we can rewrite it as
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{C}\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}.   
\end{equation*}
However, this results in the equation
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{C}^n\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}.   
\end{equation*}
that holds for every $n\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$. Provided that $\mathbf{C}^n\to \mathbf{0}$ as $n\to \infty$, taking limits at both side, we get
\begin{equation*}
    \lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbf{x}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbf{C}^n\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}.
\end{equation*}
Hence, the unique solution to this system is the trivial solution, so the rank of the square matrix $(\mathbf{I}-\mathbf{A})$ is maximum (by Rouché-Frobenius' theorem) and we can define its inverse.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elegant answer.