# What is $\mathrm{rank}(A)$ if it is known that $A^4 = 0$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Given $A \in M_{5 \times 5} (\mathbb F)$, what are the options for $\mathrm{rank}(A)$ if it is known:
>
> (I) $A^4 = 0$
>
> (II) $A^3 = 0$
>
> (III) $A^2 = 0$

Now, I am very new to ***Jordan Forms*** and this is related, but I have no clue whatsoever on the relationship between Jordan Form, and knowing the Rank of a matrix. All I know is that to calculate how much Jordan blocks of size $k x k$ there are involves an equation using ranks.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The Jordan form shows that if $[A]_{ii} = \lambda$, then $[A^k]_{ii} = \lambda^k$. So all the above conditions imply that the diagonal of $A$ is zero. Then the conditions give restrictions on the size of the Jordan blocks. Figure out what this means for the rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $J_A$ be a JNF for $A$. You know that for some invertible $P$ you have $A=PJ_AP^{-1}$, therefore $0=A^4=PJ_A^4P^{-1}$, therefore $J_A^4=0$. Now think about what $J_A$ looks like and consider its powers, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326688/why-the-nth-power-of-a-jordan-matrix-involves-the-binomial-coefficient) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Powers). Also recall that $\operatorname{rank}(A)=\operatorname{rank}(J_A)$, (why?).

Comment: All I could realize is that all the $\lambda$ are $0$.

Comment: @TheNotMe That is true, but you don't need JNF for that. Try to figure what does $J_A$ look like. There are multiple looks it might get. You'll have to check case by case, but since it's only a $5\times 5$ matrix. There aren't that many. I suggest you start by assuming [WLOG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality) that $J_A$ has its jordan blocks in descending (or ascending) order with respect to their size.

Comment: @TheNotMe Do you need extra help with this?

Comment: @TheNotMe Anytime.