# Using factorisation, $A=PJP^{-1}$ to compute $A^k$

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

Using factorisation, $A=PJP^{-1}$ to compute $A^k$, where $k$ represents an arbitrary positive integer.

$$ \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{1} \\ \mathbf{-1} & \mathbf{2} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{0} \\ \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{1} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{1} \\ \mathbf{0} & \mathbf{1} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{1} & \mathbf{0} \\ \mathbf{-1} & \mathbf{1} \end{bmatrix}. $$

Not sure how to finish this problem as the matrix $J$ is not diagonal, but $J^k$ can still be found somehow. How exactly is $J^k$ obtained in this case?

Comment: Have you looked for a pattern for $J^2$, $J^3$, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

You have basically put your matrix $A$ in [Jordan normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form).
This means that you can split your matrix $J$ as follows:
$$J = D + N$$
where $D$ is diagonal and $N$ is nilpotent, i.e. there exists an a positive integer $n$ such that $N^n = 0$.

In your case
$$J = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
=
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}}_{=D}
+
\underbrace{
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}}_{=N}
$$
and in your case you have $N^2 = 0$.

The basic idea is that when you expand your power $J^k = (D+N)^k$ using the binomial theorem, terms with $N^i$ with $i \geq n$ will disappear, since $N^n = 0$. In your case:
$$(D+N)^k = {k \choose 0} D^k + {k \choose 1} D^{k-1}N + \dots$$
where the remaining terms will be zero, e.g. the next term will be
$${k \choose 2}D^{k-2} \underbrace{N^2}_{=0} = 0.$$

More information can be found in [this math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326688/why-does-the-n-th-power-of-a-jordan-matrix-involve-the-binomial-coefficient).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily prove (for example with induction) that

$${\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1  \\ 0 & 1  \\  \end{pmatrix}}^k=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & k  \\ 0 & 1  \\  \end{pmatrix}$$

Now $A^k$ can be computed as follows:

$A^k=(S^{-1}BS)^{k}=\underbrace{S^{-1}BS\cdot S^{-1}BS\dots   S^{-1}BS}_{k \text{ times }}=S^{-1}B^{k}S=S^{-1}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & k  \\ 0 & 1  \\  \end{pmatrix}S$

Answer (score -1):

Hint: It is related to the [Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form).