# How to write the matrix exponential, if our matrix is in Jordan normal form.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

I have a $4\times4$ matrix $A$, which is composed of two $2 \times 2$ Jordan blocks.

The matrix in question is the matrix associated with a particular system of differential equations.

so,
$$e^{Ax} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{A^kx^k}{k!} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{  \begin{bmatrix}
L & 0  \\
0 & K   \end{bmatrix} ^kx^k}{k!} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{  \begin{bmatrix}
L^k & 0  \\
0 & K^k   \end{bmatrix} x^k}{k!}$$

I feel uncomfortable manipulating block matrices(block matrix-vector multiplication).

**what would be the next step?**

I would like to have something along the lines of $e^{Kx}e^{Lx}$
I could try:

$$e^{A} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{A^k}{k!} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{  \begin{bmatrix}
L & 0  \\
0 & K   \end{bmatrix} ^k}{k!} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\frac{  \begin{bmatrix}
L^k & 0  \\
0 & K^k   \end{bmatrix} }{k!}= \begin{bmatrix}
e^L & 0  \\
0 & e^K   \end{bmatrix}$$

Then $e^{Ax} = [e^A]^x =[\begin{bmatrix}
e^L & 0  \\
0 & e^K   \end{bmatrix} ]^x = \color{red}{\begin{bmatrix}
e^{Lx} & 0  \\
0 & e^{Kx}   \end{bmatrix}}$
Would this logic work out?

Comment: Yes, the exponential can be taken clockwise. See also [Why does the $n$-th power of a Jordan matrix involve the binomial coefficient?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326688/why-does-the-n-th-power-of-a-jordan-matrix-involve-the-binomial-coefficient) for the explicit form of the matrix exponential of a Jordan block.

Comment: Thanks, I worked that part out by decomposing A into a diagonal matrix(containing eigenvectors) and the off diagonal parts, It was just bridging the gap. Let me edit my post.

Comment: Is that statement, i.e $e^{Ax} = \text{ red matrix}$ legitimate?

Comment: The red one is OK, but the two in the middle are unnecessary complications, because you have yet to define $(e^A)^x$. You have shown in the displayed line that $e^A=\pmatrix{e^L\\ & e^K}$ whenever $A$ is **in the form of** $\pmatrix{L\\ &K}$. So, in particular, if you let $xA$ takes the role of $A$ (I suppose that $x$ is a scalar), then you immediately get $e^{xA}=\pmatrix{e^{xL}\\ &e^{xK}}$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you :)