# Is $A^2$ is diagonalizable , then is $A$ diagonalizable when $A$ is non-singular?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I have a question in mind which is a slight generalization of a past question(famous).
See here [if $A^2 \in M_{3}(\mathbb{R})$ is diagonalizable then so is $A$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49864/if-a2-in-m-3-mathbbr-is-diagonalizable-then-so-is-a) if you want the basic version.
Now my question : If $A^2$ is diagonalizable , then is $A$ diagonalizable when $A$ is non-singular?
Obviously, the previous counterexample of taking $A$ to be a nilpotent matrix of index will not work here as then $|A|=0$.
Any proofs?

Comment: The answer is yes. Your question can be generalized to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2349701/81360)

Answer (score 5):

People are showing that the answer is yes. Someone should point out that the answer is yes *if* we're talking about an algebraically closed field (for example if $A$ is real and we're allowing a *complex* matrix to do the diaogonalizing.)

For example if $$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1
\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$$then $A^2=I$ is certainly diagonalizable, but $A$ has no real eigenvalues, so $A$ is not diagonalizable over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: A typo, $A^2=-I$.

Answer (score 1):

We use:

> $A$ is diagonalizable if and only if the minimal polynomial for $A$ has no repeated roots.

Also:

> Given $A$ and a polynomial $p$ such that $p(A)=0,$ then $p(x)$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Now, let $m(x)$ be the minimal polynomial for $A^2.$

If $m(x)$ has no repeated roots, then $p(x)=m(x^2)$ can only have $x=0$ as a repeated root. (I'll leave that to you to prove.)

But $p(A)=0$, so $p(x)$ is divisible by the minimal polynomial of $A.$ If $A$ is non-singular, then $0$ is not a root of the minimal polynomial for $A.$ So the minimal polynomial for $A$ has no repeated roots.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth mentioning that you use this fact: if $p(A) = 0$, then the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $p(x)$.  Depending on one's definition of the minimal polynomial, this may or may not be a trivial observation.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks. Edited.