# Limit of Jordan Form and the largest eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

As an intermediate step of my homework solution, I want to show that

$$\lim_{k\to\infty} J^k=0$$

if $\max |\lambda_i|<1$, where $J$ is the Jordan form of a matrix $A$ and $\lambda_i$ denotes the $i$-th eigenvalue of $A$.

Assume this is true. I try to prove it entry by entry. This is really messy.

Is this statement indeed true? is there any shortcut to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Going entry-by-entry is enough.
You can compute a [general form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326688/why-does-the-n-th-power-of-a-jordan-matrix-involve-the-binomial-coefficient) of $J_i^k$ (where $J_i$ is the $i$th block)
to see that the entries that are $j$ steps above the main diagonal equal $\binom{k}{j} \lambda^{k-j}$, which tends to zero as $k \to \infty$ since $|\lambda| < 1$ and $\binom{k}{j} \le  k^j / j! = O(k^j)$.

Comment: To avoid such a calculation on individual entries, one could use the Jordan–Chevalley decomposition. Roughly the same inequality would be needed.

Comment: What do you mean by $\binom{k}{j}\leq k^j/j!=O(k^j)$? Why is this true?