# How to prove the limit $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\lambda^{k-j}\binom{k}{k-j}=0,\; k>j,$ and $k\gt j$

Tags: linear-algebra, limits

I find difficulty proving the following limit:

> Suppose $|\lambda|<1$,then
>   $$
> \lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}\lambda^{k-j}\binom{k}{k-j}=0,\quad k>j.
> $$

When I try to prove that the $k$th Jordan matrix converges to $0$ ... (Please see [this earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326688/why-does-the-n-th-power-of-a-jordan-matrix-involve-the-binomial-coefficient).)

Comment: *Hont.* For each fixed $j$, the binomial coefficient $\binom{k}{k-j}$ is a polynomial of $k$.

Comment: *Hant.* Stirling's formula may be of use, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: @SangchulLee I see it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @P.Quinton That's formula is quite useful. Thanks a lot!.

Comment: What happens when you try to prove that the kth Jordan matrix converges to $0$?

Comment: @jordan_glen https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/326688/why-does-the-n-th-power-of-a-jordan-matrix-involve-the-binomial-coefficient I met this in the last step of the proof.

Comment: Okay, I've added a link to that question (in your question), to provide more context for this question here.  Cheers!